# ionic cloud build failed(command:ionic package build android)

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I used following commands

```
ionic package build android
```

Some output info:

```
✔ Uploading snapshot - done!
[OK] Uploaded snapshot fc6555aa-2665-41a3-9c4b-73565623e17d!
✔ Requesting project upload - done!
✔ Uploading project - done!
✔ Queuing build - done!
[OK] Build 1 has been submitted!
```

But the package status of my app is faild on the cloud.

Follows is error message:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/opt/android-sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-oracle
Error: Could not find gradle wrapper within Android SDK. Might need to update your Android SDK.
Looked here: /opt/android-sdk/tools/templates/gradle/wrapper
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add android platform first before sending it to the cloud for building.

> ionic cordova platform add android